# Blocking remote access through PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, post

Getting this out of the way; I don't frequently do much in php or database programming, so I'm just trying to be extra careful in this current project.

So basically, I have a site powered by a database and I have some Jquery code that uses the "post" method to *insert* rows into the database. As soon as I started I had my thoughts about security, seeing as people can't see my php, but can see my Javascript. As soon as I finished setting up the system I did a test and running the jquery does insert information even if I'm on a remote source...  which can obviously lead to a possible major security problem. So being as unrefined as I am, I just want to know how I should prevent this and secure the system better?

And... Please don't insult me or be rude... I understand that I may be stupid or whatever, but I'm just trying to learn!

Comment: I am sure we all would love to help, but for that, you need to make your question more clear

Comment: Can you define remote? Another machine? Another IP-address?

Comment: What is `remote access` actually? Do your site have some sort of user validation? If not your site will become a zombie

Comment: do you have any sort of login system or can anyone visit and insert rows in your db?

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I have a server which is hosting the site, and by remote, I ran the script from my own testing server and it successfully inserted information. The script itself is the SIGN UP function, so I can't block access by way of a login system...

Comment: Add captcha, and use some sort of "form token"

Comment: read the FAQ's on site, your "question" falls directly in the "don't ask" category. Narrow it down to far more specific aspects with some sort of code context

Comment: @charlietfl I did read the FAQ... It said "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers..." and I consider this a programming problem because it is specifically addressing a problem I have with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what [Cross Site Request Forgery (`CSRF`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF) and the [same origin policy sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) are designed to prevent.

From another point of view, how do you stop someone from writing a form on their site and submitting it as a POST request to your script to add junk records?

Typically CSRF protection is provided by your framework. If you want to implement it directly in PHP, it is quite simple.

1. Generate a unique token that from your server's code, and add it to the session.
2. Embed it as a hidden field in the form.
3. On the script that accepts the form, check for the presence of this hidden field.

If the field exists, match it against what is in the session, if they match - then it is a legitimate request.

If they don't match (or the field is missing), then its a remote request and you can reject it.

[This page](http://www.serversidemagazine.com/php/php-security-measures-against-csrf-attacks/) provides some PHP code to implement the above.

Once you have done that, you need to make sure that the jquery script can be authenticated the same way. [This snippet](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118) details steps to implement the same technique in jquery.

Comment: Thank you, thank you VERY much! This is exactly what I was asking about and has everything I need! :)